# Barbell squat breathing problem

Tags: squats, breathing

Being in a good shape it's sometimes for me hard to breathe (I need to breath more and deeper) after doing barbell squats, especially after long omissions. Almost none of other exercises make me feel so breathless.

I'm thinking that this is because of a large weight of muscles in legs and totally not enough blood to serve.

What exercises can be added to train, maybe, lungs?

**UPD:** I have no cardio problems so. And yes, I will consult with my physician as soon as I can. I think the answer I will receive would be useful.

Comment: Are you doing any cardio style exercises or sports?

Comment: Does this happen with deadlifts too?

Comment: @Informaficker: No. My physician, who test me from time to time, said that I don't need one.

Comment: @VPeric: I think not, maybe in a much less manner.

Comment: I think squats are just hard. Squats use a lot of muscle, and they can grab a lot of oxygen. Is it actually hard to breath, like hard to fill your lungs? Or just that you feel out of breath?

Comment: How many reps are you doing per set?

Comment: @Kate: 3 * 15 reps. I think, this is just more like I need to breath more and more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have no heart or lung problems, you're just feeling the difficulty of doing squats. 15 reps is a long set! The program I'm doing has me doing squats at only 3 sets of 5 reps, but at a higher weight. I don't run out of breath, but they're still really hard, and I'm getting stronger. At 15 reps, you're training endurance, and that's why you're feeling so out of breath.

Comment: endurance at 15 for legs ? I do not think so.

Answer (score 0):

The real answer is oxygen debt during the set. It is the same effect  as with  sprinting all-out. http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/oxygen+debt